# laravel javascript URL error to get the data from mysql

Tags: javascript, laravel, controller

i have this error in my text/javascript in laravel, I want to do is to get the fw_number for url that will show the data of the fw_number but it pointing to wrong data column which is the fw_status, so the url shows like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/fw/Open

blade.html

```
<div class="row">
           <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
                <h5 class="text-truncate col-10 mt-3"> <span class="fas fa-exchange-alt icons"></span> <b> Activity & History</b></h5>
                <hr class="col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11"></hr>
                <label class="form-label for_label"><b>Add Comment</b></label>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 ">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="stg_comment" rows="2"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
                       <button type="button" id="btn_comment" class="btn btn-block btn-secondary mt-1">COMMENT</button>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-11 col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 ">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-fw-widget">
                        @foreach($curstages as $stages)
                        
                        <tr class="tr-comment" >
                        
                                @if($stages->cmstg_dateaction != "" && $stages->cmstg_stage != "REV2")
                                    <td width="15%" class="bs-callout bs-callout-info td-comment">{{date('m-d-Y H:i', strtotime($stages->cmstg_dateaction))}}</td>
                                    @if($stages->cmstg_desc == "Cancelled")
                                    <td width="40%"><b>FW {{$stages->cmstg_desc}}</b> by Requestor ({{$fw->userbasic->user_xfirstname.' '.$fw->userbasic->user_xlastname}})</td>
                                    @elseif($stages->cmstg_stage == "DH" )
                                    <td width="40%"><b>FW {{$stages->cmstg_desc}}</b> by Department Head ({{$stages->userbasic->user_xfirstname.' '.$stages->userbasic->user_xlastname}})</td>
                                    @elseif($stages->cmstg_stage == "ITOPS" )
                                    <td width="40%"><b>FW {{$stages->prstg_desc}}</b> by IT-Operations Head ({{$stages->userbasic->user_xfirstname.' '.$stages->userbasic->user_xlastname}})</td>
                                    @elseif($stages->cmstg_stage == "NETAD" )
                                    <td width="40%"><b>FW {{$stages->prstg_desc}}</b> by Network Administration ({{$stages->userbasic->user_xfirstname.' '.$stages->userbasic->user_xlastname}})</td>
                                    @elseif($stages->cmstg_stage == "COM" )
                                    <td width="40%"><b>Firewall Request Comment </b>by ({{$stages->userbasic->user_xfirstname.' '.$stages->userbasic->user_xlastname}})</td>
                                         @elseif($stages->cmstg_stage == "REV" )
                                        @php 
                                        $position = $stages->rev_stage;
                                        $value = $position;
                                        if($position == "DH") $value = "Department Head";
                                        elseif($position == "ITOPS") $value = "IT-Operations Head";
                                        elseif($position == "NETAD") $value = "Network Administration";
                                       

                                        @endphp

                                        <td width="40%"><b>PR {{$stages->cmstg_desc}} </b>by {{$value}} ({{$stages->userbasic->user_xfirstname.' '.$stages->userbasic->user_xlastname}})</td>

                                    @endif
                                    <td width="40%"><b>Notes: </b>{{$stages->cmstg_note}}</td>
                                @elseif($stages->cmstg_stage == "REV2" )
                                <td width="15%" class="bs-callout bs-callout-warning td-comment">{{date('m-d-Y H:i', strtotime($stages->cmstg_dateaction))}}</td>
                                <td width="40%" ><b>Request for Revision </b>by ({{$stages->userbasic->user_xfirstname.' '.$stages->userbasic->user_xlastname}})</td>
                                <td width="40%"><b>Notes: </b>{{$stages->cmstg_note}}</td>
                            
                                @endif
                        </tr>
                       @endforeach
                           
                            <tr class="tr-comment" >
                                <td class="bs-callout bs-callout-dark td-comment">{{date('m-d-Y H:i', strtotime($fw->created_at))}}</td>
                                <td><b>Firewall Request Submitted</b></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

this the text/javascript

```
$('#table4 tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
            
            var url = '{{route("fw.show",["fw" => ":fwnum"])}}';
            
            url = url.replace(':fwnum',$(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
            
            location.href = url;
        });
```

this the controller of show

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $fw = FirewallRequest::with('userbasic')->where('fw_number',$id)->first();
        $fwcomment = FirewallComment::with('userbasic')
        ->selectRaw('ifnull(approval_dateaction,created_at),comment_user_id,ifnull(revision_desc,""),comment,if(revision = "1","REV",if(revision = "2","REV2","COM")),revision_stage')
        ->where('fw_number',$id);

        $curstages = ChangeManagementStages::with('userbasic')
        ->selectRaw('cmstg_dateaction,cmstg_user,cmstg_desc,cmstg_note,cmstg_stage,"" as revise_stage')
        ->where('cmstg_cmnumber',$id)->union($fwcomment)->orderby('cmstg_dateaction','desc')->get();
        

        $now = ChangeManagementStages::where('cmstg_cmnumber',$id)->whereNotnull('cmstg_desc')->orderBy('cmstg_id','desc')->first();
        $upcoming = ChangeManagementStages::where('cmstg_cmnumber',$id)->wherenull('cmstg_desc')->first();
        $approval =  $now->cmstg_desc ?? '';
        $latest_approver = $approval == "Acknowledged" ? $now->cmstg_user  : $upcoming->cmstg_user ?? '';
        //dd($fw->userbasic);
        $user = auth()->user()->status_xuser;
        $count = 1;
        session(['message'=>'Request Firewall','icon'=>'bi bi-bezier2 nav_icon  ','icon-code'=>'']);

        return view('pages.change_management.cm_firewall.show', compact(['fw','curstages','now','upcoming','approval','latest_approver','user','count','fwcomment']));

        
    }
```

Comment: You have a click event on the `tr` and use `$(this).closest('tr')`, i don't know your html. Are you sure you want the id of a parent element tr? also make sure the id is unique for the page. If you want to use the id from a model, you should use a data attribute, and not the id attribute:  `data-id` for example. (read with `$(this).data('id')`)

Comment: i put the blade.php if you want to take a look at it thank you